# How to associate cordova application to windows store?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to corodova(visual studio plugin)  i wrote a simple application and want to associate with windows store but the option is disabled.
project -> right click -> store -> Associate app with store ( disabled) , is there something i am missing or is there any other way to associate this application to store.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Select `Windows Phone Universal` as the build configuration (drop down menu at the top of Visual Studio).  It won't be enabled for iOS, Android, etc.

Hope this helps.